# wp.template() Not a function

Tags: admin, javascript

When I console.log(wp) the object only includes:
-wp.emoji
-wp.heartbeat
-wp.svgPainter

Script is loaded in the footer and last in the DOM. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, I get it. When you enqueue your admin script, add 'wp-util' as a dependancy.

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'script.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-util' ), '1.0', true );
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, be sure to accept and mark it as correct.

Comment: :@Justin W Hall:

Comment: Where to put this text....

Comment: In your plugin or functions.php

Comment: perfect! saved me a lot of time!

Comment: This simple answer saved my day. It works perfectly!

Comment: This is weird but... it works. It causes a JS error in console but then the functionality is restored

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had W3 Total Cache installed, and Minify option was set to Manual.

After I removed wp-underscore script from manual minify list, issue with the `wp.template() Not a function` was gone.